# Adobe Flash builder - Flex - Android - How to get time and date in a label?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, date, time, builder

I'm a newbie to Flex and I'd like someone to help me out with this. I want to add 2 label with its text being set as Date and Time. The 2 labels would display the current date and current time. I have surfed a lot on the internet but I couldn't find anything! Could someone be really kind and help me out with this? I'd greatly appreciate your help!
Thanks,
osama

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work in its simplest form:

```
<s:Label id="dateLabel" text="{(new Date()).toDateString()}"/>
<s:Label id="timeLabel" text="{(new Date()).toTimeString()}"/>
```

This will, in essence, create a new date object which represents the current date and time.  Then the [toDateString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#toDateString%28%29) or [toTimeString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#toTimeString%28%29) methods will be executed; and the value will be displayed in the label.

If you have a date object through some other means, such as returned from a server side object or remote service call; you can set the label's text in ActionScript:

```
dateLabel.text = myDateObject.toDateString();
timeLabel.text = myDateObject.toTimeString();
```

Comment: If you believe this accurately and completely answers your question; please mark it as the answer.  There should be a "checkbox" to the left of the question.